# bigquery error:Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

started getting "error:Unexpected. Please try again" with a simple query on a table. I use streaming updates on the table. Other streaming tables in the project works fine.

This table has been working fine, but I started to get errors yesterday and it now consistantly fail any Query. Please help !

Query Text:

SELECT * FROM [rawdata.5299280705224704_Visits_v2_] LIMIT 1000;
Errors:

Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID:salgsbox:job_yp9Es3Qhyh5hJNdsoT7Ubszzdmk

Comment: Are you sure that is the right job id? I can't find it in the logs.

Comment: Nope, the paste must have gone bad. Here is the right one Job ID: salgsbox:job_yp9Es3Qhyh5hJNdsoT7Ubszzdmk

Comment: Great thanks. It seams that any query against that table fails.

Comment: Hi Jordan. I appreciate you are looking into this. Can you say anything about when I can expect this to be fixed. My costumer is asking when it will be resolved so that they can access our application again. Alternatively a workaround to get access to query the table again would be great.

Comment: Its working again now :)

Comment: Yep ... our release just went out a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the handling of streaming data related to a recent configuration change. It should now be fixed.

Comment: As of this morning I'm now getting this error again on the same table. How do i resolve this problem ? Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: salgsbox:job_NJY6w_tyN48RDZ2moqI9LfItkN8

Comment: The table can be queried again now