# Bigquery Job Failing with 500 Internal Error

Tags: google-bigquery

This is really a question for Jordan Tigani and Google's BigQuery support that recommends we use stackoverflow:

I have a BigQuery job that has been executing daily for the past several months but now has started erroring out with an internal 500 error.  One example is job id job_4J9LL4vp3xtM30WgqduvQqFFUN4 - would it be possible to know why this job is causing an internal bigquery error and if there's something I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same issue as [bigquery error:Unexpected. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568573/bigquery-errorunexpected-please-try-again)

We've got a fix that we're currently testing, it should go out in this week's release. Unfortunately, there is no workaround, other than to use a table decorator that doesn't include the latest streaming data.